# Url encodings with greek characters

Tags: objective-c, url, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

I get the html source of a page to a NSString like this

```
NSString* url = @"example url";
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8 error:&err];
```

a part of the response is like : [2 \u00cf\u0083\u00cf\u0087\u00cf\u008c\u00ce\u00bb\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00b1](http://odysonline.gr/2011/02/ayga-matia/#comments)

How can i have the Greek characters shown as they should in the NSString response?

The encoding of the page is "charset=iso-8859-7"

Comment: To demonstrate the problem, could you provide a valid http:// style URL in your example above?  Also, you know the encoding is "iso-8859-7", why are you forcing the response to be kCFStringEncodingUTF8?  If there is not a iso-8859-7 constant to be explicitly passed in the encoding parameter, why not try the "usedEncoding" version of stringWithContentsOfURL?

Comment: Michael Dautermann i tested all the possible encodings.. the encoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8 it was one of them. A valid url is [link](www.blog.gr) for example. I managed to make it work but with utf-8 pages but not with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, I understand your question a little bit better now.

The Apple-supplied native implementation of NSString doesn't know what to do with iso-8859-7 encoding.

You have two options.

1)

Try requesting different encodings to [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding: error:] to see if one successfully loads.  My first attempt would be with NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.

2)

I found a third party library (and NSString category extension) that *does* do iso-8859-7 conversion.  But to get access to CkoCharset will cost you (or your client) $290 USD. It might be a worthwhile investment to save time & hassle.

https://chilkatsoft.com/charset-objc.asp

and documentation is here:

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/objcCkoCharsetRef.html